# Github Action boolean input with default value

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm developing a GitHub Action for marketplace. It has various inputs with default values. One of these inputs happen to be a `boolean` which I use to toggle debugging status.

Here's my boolean input definition:

```yaml
inputs:
  debug_mode:
    description: "Controls the debug mode, boolean, true is for on. When turned on, it'll output certain information on certain steps. Mainly used for development, but use it as you please to inspect your env and variables."
    type: boolean
    required: false
    default: false
```

As you can see it has the type `boolean` with default value `false`.
Then in one of the steps, I check `debug_mode` to determine whether to run the step or not. However, it is not working as expected:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Dump debug_mode
    run: echo "debug_mode is ${{ inputs.debug_mode }}"
    shell: bash
  - name: Dump context
    if: ${{ inputs.debug_mode}}
    uses: crazy-max/ghaction-dump-context@v2
  - name: Dump build_path
    if: ${{ inputs.debug_mode}}
    run: echo "build_path is ${{ inputs.build_path }}"
```

When the action runs, I see that `debug_mode is false` is printed via `echo`. Nonetheless, 'Dump Context' step runs even though `debug_mode` is false. I tried giving this input value explicitly `true` or `false`, also tried it without assigning a value (using default), still didn't get a consistent result. I read somewhere that it could be due to the fact I'm running in via `workflow_run`.

For reference and easier time detecting the issue, here is the original sources:

- Action itself: https://github.com/skywarth/vite-vue-github-pages-deploy/blob/master/action.yml
- Where I'm testing/using the action: https://github.com/skywarth/country-routing-algorithm-demo-vue/blob/master/.github/workflows/deploy-using-published-action.yml
- Sample workflow run: https://github.com/skywarth/country-routing-algorithm-demo-vue/actions/runs/5027772997

In clearance, my aim is to run certain steps only if `debug_mode` is `true`. I would like to use `boolean` type if possible, because string is semantically incorrect.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For actions, `type` parameter is not supported for [`inputs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#inputs).

Maybe, you thought it would be the same as [`on.workflow_dispatch.inputs.<input_id>.type`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputsinput_idtype) but it is not.

As for `default`, it takes a `string` value, not a Boolean. See its JSON schema [here](https://json.schemastore.org/github-action.json). VS Code automatically highlights these issues using this JSON schema. You might have to install its [GitHub Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-github-actions) extension.

If you want to handle it under Boolean context, use `'true'` or `'false'` as strings and use it accordingly.

So, the `inputs` would be:

```yaml
inputs:
  debug_mode:
    description: '...'
    required: false
    default: 'false'
```

and, for `true` case, the `if` condition would be:

```yaml
if: ${{ inputs.debug_mode == 'true' }}
```

Comment: Well, it's a shame that boolean type inputs are not supported yet. I guess I'll have to resort to using strings then. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: The `if` control doesn't require brackets. You can do `if: inputs.debug_mode == 'true'`.

Comment: If you don't specify a default but do include `type: boolean` and `required: false`, then the default value will be null and the if condition should work with that too `if: ${{ inputs.debug_mod }}` should be falsy with null

Comment: @justin.m.chase: What do you mean by including `type: boolean` here?

Comment: Inputs can be of type boolean, the problem appears to be if you set the default then it will end up being a string instead of a boolean. But if you just type it as boolean and dont set a default then it will be an actual boolean or null, which lets your logic work without doing the weird string hacks (I think).

Comment: @justin.m.chase: There's no `type` input parameter for actions. The OP's question is about actions, not workflows. Regarding workflows, specifically for `workflow_dispatch` event, you might want to take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77878770/github-actions-job-always-running-even-with-conditional).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the choice option.

```
inputs:
  debug_mode:
    description: "Your Description"
    type: choice
    required: true
    default: 'false'
    options:
      - true
      - false
```

This way you can restrict what users can provide as input.

To check the value:

```
if: ${{ inputs.debug_mode == 'true' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the default value is converted to a string while the inputs are actually booleans. What seems to finally be working for me is just checking both string and boolean:

```
if: ${{ inputs.debug_mode == true || inputs.debug_mode == 'true' }}
```