# Github Actions Job always running even with conditional

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github actions workflow dispatch that takes some input.  i have three jobs within it.  The second and Third jobs should depend on the first completing successfully, plus the second Job should only run if a checkbox input is true, and the third job should only run if another checkbox input is true.

This is what I currently have, but its not working as I expect, the second and third jobs do not run:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      input1:
        type: boolean
        description: input 1 desc
        default: true
      input2:
        type: boolean
        description: input 2 desc
        default: false
      input3:
        type: string
        description: input 3 desc

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-company-short-ids.outputs.IDS_ARRAY }}
    steps:
      - name: Create array of ids
        id: set-ids
        run: |
          echo "IDS_ARRAY=$(echo '"${{ github.event.inputs.input3 }}"' | tr -d ' ' | jq -c 'split(",")')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          
  job2:
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.input1 == true }}
    needs: job1
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        target: ${{ fromJSON(needs.job1.outputs.matrix) }}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusableWorkflow.yml
  
  job3:
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.input2 == true }}
    needs: job1
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        target: ["once"]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusableWorkflow.yml
```

When I add a debug step to job1 I can see the values come thru true and false.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event:

> When the workflow runs, you can access the input values in the `inputs` context.

> The workflow will also receive the inputs in the `github.event.inputs` context. **The information in the `inputs` context and `github.event.inputs` context is identical except that the `inputs` context preserves Boolean values as Booleans instead of converting them to strings.** ...

As you're using `github.event.inputs` context, the values are converted to strings. You need to compare against strings:

```yaml
if: ${{ github.event.inputs.input1 == 'true' }}
```

or, use the `inputs` context:

```yaml
if: ${{ inputs.input1 == true }}
```

---

Apart from that, you need to fix `outputs` in `job1`. The step `id` is not what you're using to set the output parameter. You may use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to lint your workflow for syntax issues.

Comment: Yes, thanks this is the solution.  I was using github.event.inputs.input1 so it was converted to a string.  Thankyou